# How to set a default open SlidingDrawer

Tags: android

I have a SlidingDrawer in an Activity, at the bottom. The functionality to open this SlidingDrawer is implemented on clicking of a button. I just want to open this SlidingDrawer as the default state of this. i.e. as My screen resumes, the SlidingDrawer's default state is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `open()` on the drawer object in your `oncreate()`.

See both answers here:
[Android Sliding Drawer Open On Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244387/android-sliding-drawer-open-on-create)

Comment: Thanks.. Its working well for Me actually what I need... Thanks for paying attention on that issue