# Is it possible to make opened SlidingDrawer?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

When I start my applications, almost slidingdrawer is closed, but I want to make opened slidingdrawer from the beginning.

How can I do this?

I've tried to use offset or dispatchDraw, but I didn't make it.

Comment: SEE HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244387/android-sliding-drawer-open-on-create

Answer (score 1):

Use slide.open in onCreate();

```
slide.open(); 
slide.setOnDrawerScrollListener(this);

@Override
public void onScrollStarted() {
    if (slide.isOpened()) {
    }
    else {
        slide.open(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  [`SlidingDrawer.open()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html#open%28%29) at the end of `onCreate`.

This is not advised, keeping the menu open everytime will reduce interest in usage of the app.

use `SharedPreferences` to store the number times that uses has used & show the user only for first few times.

```
    if (mStorage.getAppOpenedTimes() < 2)
    {
        SlidingDrawer.open();
    }
```

But, you can ignore all the above if keeping the menu opened is necessary in your app.